# How to read a word document in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read a word document in asp.net and i need to convert the document words into bytes .So how to do that ?

Comment: Exactly what kind of document do you mean? What program created it? Exactly what do you want to do with the document?

Comment: Hi John, i want to convert those characters which are in document and convert into bytes and bytes to character

Comment: What do you plan to then do with the characters?

Comment: thanx for reply. i want to insert those bytes into database

Comment: What kind of document? Which program created the document?

Answer (score 2):

Kumar,

We are not just going to give you the code. You need to have a specific problem.

Your first step will be to figure out what steps your programme will need to take in order to achieve your goal.

Look at your problem. What do you think will need to happen? You don't write this in code, but in plain "English"*.

For example:

1. Load in the file

   - Whatever sub steps this requires
2. Parse the file as a word document

   - Whatever sub steps this requires
3. Get the bytes for each word in the document

   - Whatever sub steps this requires
4. Profit

Then look into how to write the code you will require to achieve each sub step.

If you have issues with best practices, technicalities in your code, or something else specific to coding that will probably have a definitive answer, you should ask it at Stack Overflow.

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

- https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/howdoi/?p=190
- http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=1006
- http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/316480-reading-text-from-ms-word-files-in-c%23/

*I say English, but I really mean which ever language is most relevant to you.